# LINQ Lambda Expression (Fluent Programming) to retrieve an average of multiple occurrences

Tags: c#, linq

The below LINQ works for retrieving `CellSignalStrength` of a single `CellInfoLte` in `AllCellInfo`, but I discovered that there are multiple `CellInfoLte` in `AllCellInfo`; so I’m trying to take an average of `CellSignalStrength` of all `CellInfoLte` instances (`IEnumerator`) in `AllCellInfo`, but I don’t have experience dealing with multiple instances and taking an average of them.

Can someone help me convert the below LINQ to retrieve an average of multiple `CellInfoLte` and explain the changes in the code to handle multiple occurrences and taking an average of them?  I thank you in advance for your help.

```
private CellSignalStrength _cellSignalStrength;
private CellInfoLte _cellInfoLte;
private int _mobilLTEAvgSignal = 0;

// ...

_cellInfoLte = (CellInfoLte)_mTelMgr.AllCellInfo
    .Where(c => c.GetType() == typeof(CellInfoLte))
    .FirstOrDefault();

_mobilLTEAvgSignal = _cellInfoLte.CellSignalStrength.Dbm;
```

Comment: Linq has the method [`OfType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype?view=netframework-4.7.2) that you might want to check out.

Comment: Hi Lews, Thank you making my question more readable!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `Average` LINQ method:

```
var average = _mTelMgr.AllCellInfo
                      .OfType<CellInfoLte>()
                      .Average(c => c.CellSignalStrength.Dbm);
```

This code finds all `CellInfoLte` instances in collections (`OfType<CellInfoLte>`), gets `CellSignalStrength.Dbm` values, and calculates the average (`Average`).

Comment: `.OfType<CellInfoLte>().Average(c => c.CellSignalStrength.Dbm)` would be better.

Comment: Hi Ingvar & Juharr, Thank you for your answers! I really appreciate it. You guys have opened a new door for me in the world of LINQ Lamda Expressions - thank you!